# Что такое алгоритм "минимакс" в игре "шашки"?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi

Что такое алгоритм "минимакс" в игре "шашки". Расскажите, пожалуйста, простым языком. Если можно, дайте, пожалуйста, пример на языке Delphi.

Comment: В поисковике из топ 10 http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81  это кажись оно. Реализацию на делфях вам безплатно никто не даст. Применительно к каждому отдельному случаю реализация будет разной. Если это задание с ВУЗа - читайте методичку.

Comment: Есть и другие значения http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_mathematics/3118

Comment: кто-то проголосовал за переоткрытие, а комментария, поясняющего это предложение, нет.

Comment: Термин минимакс имеет много значений. Нужно уточнить вопрос. Попробую перечислись. 1) принцип поиска решения в комп играх (это в первом значении). 2) тупо min + max в одной функции. 3) min от функции ограниченой максимумом. 4) минимальный из максимумов.  Как вариант - общий ответ сделать.

Answer (score 3):

[Минимакс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81) — правило принятия решений, используемое в теории игр, теории принятия решений, исследовании операций, статистике и философии для минимизации возможных потерь из тех, которые лицу, принимающему решение, нельзя предотвратить при развитии событий по наихудшему для него сценарию.

[Пример](http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread1903686.html):

```
Procedure Tform1.minimax;
var i,j:integer;
begin
min:=0;max:=0;
for i:=1 to 20 do
maxi[i]:=0;
k:=0;
for i:=1 to StringGrid1.ColCount-3 do
  begin
  max:=tab[i,1];
    for j:=1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do
      begin
        if max<tab[i,j] then max:=tab[i,j];
      end;
    maxi[i]:=max;
  end;
    for i:=1 to 20 do
  min:=maxi[1];
  for j:=1 to StringGrid1.colCount-3 do
    if min>maxi[j] then min:=maxi[j];
end;

Procedure Tform1.maximin;
var i,j:integer;
begin
min:=0;max:=0;
  for i:=1 to 20 do mini[i]:=0;
    for j:=1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do 
      begin
        min:=tab[1,j];
        for i:=1 to StringGrid1.colCount-1 do
          begin
            if min>tab[i,j] then min:=tab[i,j];
          end;
          mini[j]:=min;
      end;
    max:=mini[1];
  for i:=1 to StringGrid1.ColCount-1 do
    if max<mini[i] then max:=mini[i];
end;
```

Comment: Про min кажется забыли, она обьявлена, но не участвует. А.... нужно дописать что это фрагмент кода.

Comment: ага) я думал что и так будет понятно)

Comment: По примеру, я вижу что берется *минимум и максимум из массива с максимумами*.

Comment: ага) где то так